# Ruby on Rails form with collection_check_boxes in a table - has_and_belongs_to_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4, erb

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many association between my Player and Registration models (registration is for an event). When a registration list is created, I show a list of all players and collection_check_boxes to select one or more players for that registration list.

Ideally, I would like to show this list as a table. Fist column check box, second column Player.name, third column Player.club, etc.

The problem is I can't find a way to access each attribute for Player within the each do look so that I can format the table. Instead, I can only generate one label.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :player_ids, @players, :id, :first_name do |b| %>
  <%= b.check_box %>
  <%= b.label %>
<% end %>
```

I have tried creating a method within the Player model to show more attributes within the label but it's not ideal.

### Model

```
def player
  "#{first_name} #{last_name} #{club} ..."
end
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :player_ids, @players, :id, :player do |b| %>
```

Here is my code:

### Player Model

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :registrations, dependent: :destroy

  def player
    "#{first_name} #{last_name} #{club}"
  end
end
```

### Registration Model

```
class Registration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fixture
  has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end
```

### Form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@registration) do |f| %>

<div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.association :fixture %>

<table class="table col-md-4">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- check box -->
      </td>
      <th>
        Name (Primary Venue)
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :player_ids, @players, :id, :player do |b| %>
     <tr>
       <td>
        <div class="collection-check-box">
          <%= b.check_box %>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="collection-check-box">
          <%= b.label %>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My question is, how can I display this check_box collection list within a table with multiple columns referencing Player attributes?

Comment: `b.object` should give you the current item in the iteration.

Comment: Thanks. So it does return first_name in this instance. But I would like to be able to return multiple items (first_name, last_name, club, etc) then display them in a table that is searchable and filterable.